# How to remove repeating row in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i have problem How to remove repeating row in jasper report.i just want to one label and one row. How to do that?.

Anyone know about this?.
This is my first images:-
[image]
This is my second images:-
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The text field you use to show your SIRI numbers should have a 'Print Repeated Values' property. 
Uncheck this in iReport or add `isPrintRepeatedValues="false"` inside the `reportElement` tag for that field in the jrxml file.

Comment: This will just hide the repeated element and show a blank space instead.

Comment: This will just hide the repeated element and show a blank space instead..we need an effective ans.which can help us

Comment: This is working, but how to do that this row will be the last, not the first as it is now?

Comment: This will hide repeated column value but it is not merging that cells.