# More then Print Repeated Values

Tags: jasper-reports

```
Branch  ID  date    tax total
banglore    bang01  22-11-2013  450 5000
banglore    bang01  22-11-2013  350 4300
banglore    bang01  22-11-2013  450 5000
bangalore   bang02  22-11-2013  350 4300
bangalore   bang02  22-11-2013  250 2500
banglore    bang03  24-11-2013  350 4500
```

when I remove Print Repeated Values

```
Branch  ID  date    tax total
banglore    bang01  22-11-2013  450 5000
            350 4300
            450 5000
    bang02      350 4300
            250 2500
    bang03  24-11-2013  350 4500
```

but I want like this :

```
Branch  ID  date    tax total
banglore    bang01  22-11-2013  450 5000
            350 4300
            450 5000
bangalore   bang02  22-11-2013  350 4300
            250 2500
banglore    bang03  24-11-2013  350 4500
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619877/how-to-remove-repeating-row-in-jasper-report,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: You can use groups. The [Data Grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/#groups) sample